NPM not installing the highest available version of a dependency
I have an angular website, and this is a part of it's package-lock.json after running "npm install":

Why does npm installed version 5.7.1 of the semver package when it could have installed 5.7.2?
Edit:
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
Here is the package.json:
{
  "name": "internal-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-themes": "devextreme build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/core": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/router": "~17.3.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "braces": "3.0.3",
    "debug": "4.3.5",
    "devextreme": "23.2.6",
    "devextreme-angular": "23.2.6",
    "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery": "3.0.0",
    "devextreme-schematics": "1.6.9",
    "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "has-ansi": "5.0.1",
    "minimatch": "9.0.4",
    "mkdirp": "3.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "17.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~17.3.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.3.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~17.3.7",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.13",
    "@types/node": "~20.12.8",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "devextreme-cli": "1.6.9",
    "devextreme-themebuilder": "23.2.6",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5"
  }
}


Can you provide us your package.json as well ?
And does the package-lock.json already exists when you run npm i ?

yes, package-lock.json already exists

you should delete your package-lock.json, and then run npm install

Deleting package-lock.json fixed the issue.
